# Blazor and ICommand, what are the alternative and how do people not need it?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

One of the useful thing when doing xaml in either Xamarin or Maui is having the **ICommand** interface; even better with the CommunityToolkits.Mvvm.

The **ICommand** has execut and **canExecute** to make coding the press of a button very easy.

In Blazor you can try and use **ViewModels** in the same way, as services,
I'm not talking just about items in a list to decouple from the model and have more props like an **isSelected**.

But it's not really the best thing and you don't have `ICommand`.

What do you do then when managing buttons?

```
<button @onclick="OnButtonClicked" disabled="@(canButtonExecute || isButtonExecuting)>
   click me
</button>
```

You still have to make two properties, and a method to properly handle a button click or some combination of these, but the `ICommand` is not really a thing in Blazor, nor Microsoft suggest Mvvm for this framework.

There is a guy that plans to port the CommunityToolkit to Blazor but it's not like people are begging for it.

So how you all solve this issue? Not mentioning also that the disabled attribute in html can be just removed with the developer console.
Also it can be for any other case where `ICommand` is usefull and buttons arent just a way to submit forms. ( i know with the EditForm component you can use some properties of the model to make sure a button isnt clicked twice but still! )

Can you even make a custom directive to use in html components to not make a custom button element (imagine doing a blazor component as a wrapper for every html element come on)?

Like the `@onclick` but like `@command="MyCommand"`?

Comment: This is something (probaly the only thing) that I miss about Blazor. I have thought about writing a Blazor equivalent, but never got round to it. I generally just add a `bool` property which I bind to the `IsEnabled` property of the button (I use Telerik components, you may have a different proeprty, depending on whether you use the built-in components, or a 3rd party set). Not that much extra work, and basically does the same.

Comment: @HenkHolterman my bad i'm kinda tired and i mistaken something i ve done a while ago with the icommand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blazorise supports ICommand on buttons https://blazorise.com/docs/components/button

Comment: So when you set the command you dont need to seet disabled and it defaults to some sort of canExecute internally?
Also does it just apply the disabled style or also throws an exception if the user press F12 and remove the disabled attribute?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure. Where I'm working now, we aren't using it.  Download the github and try it out.

Comment: thanks i ll try it out, i cant use it a work tho but maybe i can see how they implements it.

Comment: https://github.com/Megabit/Blazorise/blob/6d63d2a62360df91ad74798b815adc8fe9c3db46/Source/Blazorise/Components/Button/Button.cs

Comment: Looks like it and as I remember, but I didn't try today. Good luck https://github.com/Megabit/Blazorise/pull/2070